# AndroidX GMS not found

Tags: android, androidx

I am trying to add a barcode scanner to my android app. I am using API 29, and I am following this guide [Barcode Scanner](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/#2) from Google. The guide tells me to add these two lines:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8+'
```

The first line is by default in my app, which is:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
```

However the second line I cannot find anywhere. How do I add GMS to AndroidX?

Comment: look at this https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#august_29_2019 you just need to add gms dependency

Comment: I know that I need to add GMS dependency, my problem is what is the dependency called for androidx

Answer (score 0):

Please add these two lines in gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```